# What is the Best way to pass information from one collection view to another more detailed collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

My app has a collection view of folders (with bunch o images data in them) and when one is selected it performs a segue to another collections view to show the images "contained" in that folder.
In core data I have two entities: folder and picture. I also have one to-many relationship from folder to picture called "pictures" and a reverse to-one relationship called "folder"

My solution is to pass the indexpath of the folder in the "performSegue" method to the second collection view controller. Then in 2nd collection view cotroller I fetch the folder record with that indexpath and  use its relationship to get the images...However I am not sure that is the way..

What is the best way to get the images in the second collection view controller ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instance of `folder` is already in your master view controller, then pass it directly to the detail view controller, instead of making a second request to core data. Because, passing the path to the index of a table would require you to also have access to this table from the detail view controller, which would result in creating a dependency between both controllers while there must be no such dependency.

Comment: I see...yes it is already in the master view controller..I know the entity "folder" has a relationship "pictures" as a NSSet type. Is this NSSet, a set of "picture" objects or some kind of path to the "picture" entities stored in core data ? Thx for your help

Comment: I assume you mean the `picture` property which is of type `NSSet` inside the `folder`, then yes, this set contains all pictures assigned to the folder. So, you can pass it directly to your detail VC. However, passing the folder may be more beneficial, if you also need to access folder properties in your detail VC (e.g. folder name).